# How to get a specific string from a url

Tags: plugins, php, wp-query, javascript, jquery

I am creating a custom WordPress theme and i am little stuck in one situation . what i want is that
http://192.168.1.50/jobifylocal/resume/paulwoods/
get the name : paulwoods in a $variable.
Note every-time there is new name instead of paulwoods, when i click on a post.
Does anybody have a clue how can i get it ?
I searched on google but no relevant problems found, and also i don't have any clue to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use this:

```
global $post;
$page_slug = $post->post_name;
```

Where $page_slug is the variable you're looking for. This has a pretty good explanation of why that works: https://blog.wplauncher.com/get-current-page-slug-wordpress/